# Best practice for populating dropdown based on other dropdown selection in web2py?

Tags: web2py

I would like to create a form that contains dropdown fields.  After entering text or selecting an option in one dropdown I would like to populate the options in another.

Is there a best practice for doing so specifically with web2py?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this [lazy options widget](https://github.com/kenji4569/sqlabs/blob/master/modules/plugin_lazy_options_widget.py) (with [usage example](https://github.com/kenji4569/sqlabs/blob/master/controllers/plugin_lazy_options_widget.py)) as well as these recipes:

- [Cascading Drop Down Lists](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1410/cascading-drop-down-lists)
- [Cascading Select Based on Python Lists](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1414/cascading-select-based-on-python-lists-as-opposed-to-a-database)
- [Cascading Drop Down Lists with Ajax](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1467/cascading-drop-down-lists-with-ajax)