# Error ticket opening web2pyslices : "admin disabled because unable to access password file"

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I was looking for options to cascaded dropdown forms for a web2py application when I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146260/best-practice-for-populating-dropdown-based-on-other-dropdown-selection-in-web2p)! But trying to open the links in the accepted answer, I get thrown a web2py ticket stating "admin disabled because unable to access password file". Can somebody tell me where am I going wrong and how can I rectify it? 
I ask this question as I have been using web2py for a couple of years now and have never come across an error like this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not going wrong -- the site was just generating an error. By default, web2py shows a link to the error ticket, but the tickets themselves are only accessible by someone with admin privileges.

The links in the SO answer to which you referred were using legacy URLs from the old web2pyslices site, and for some reason, they were (at least temporarily) not redirecting properly. I have updated that SO answer with the newer URLs, so the links should work now.